# How To bind Listview with variable in content page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to bind my list view with string variable and image in my classe.

Here is my Xalm code :

```
<ListView  x:Name="ListViewWordDescriptionOnline"
HasUnevenRows="True"
VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate  >
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell IsEnabled="False" >
                <ViewCell.View>                                   
                       <Label     Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="#7D7D7D"  FontSize="14" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label     Text="BIND WITH VARIABLE BingStringValue   IN PUBLIC CLASS"   />
                         <Image  Source=" BIND WITH IMAGE  BingImageValue IN PUBLIC CLASS" />

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here is my C# code :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {

        List<string> animals= new List<string> { "bird", "dog" };
        ListViewWordDescriptionOnline.ItemsSource=animals;

        string BingStringValue ="This is type 1"
        var BingImageValue=  ImageSource.FromResource("MyImages.WordsPage.AddWords.png");
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you want every row in your List to display the same value for BingStringValue and BingImageValue?

Comment: Yes because those value can change when doing condition inn .cs classe

Comment: use a relative binding - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Comment: *"those values can change"* To get the result you expect, you will have to move BingStringValue and BingImageValue into a separate class. I'll call it `class ItemViewModel`. If you have two items, you will have two instances of ItemViewModel, each with their OWN BingStringValue and BingImageValue. If you leave them in MainPage, then all items will look the SAME. Binding happens LATER; it doesn't happen while you are creating the items - so you can't just have one location, and change it "on the fly". Please look at any example of ListView, to see what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You alse could define a `Name` to the root contentpage,then use [Binding Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path) to bind the `BingStringValue` and `BingImageValue`.

the page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{


   public string BingStringValue { get; set; }
    public ImageSource BingImageValue { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> animals = new List<string> { "bird", "dog" };
        ListViewWordDescriptionOnline.ItemsSource = animals;
        BingStringValue = "This is type 1";
        BingImageValue = ImageSource.FromResource("NewerForms.fivePlus.png");
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

then in the xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NewerForms.Page3"
         x:Name="root"
         >
  <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <ListView  x:Name="ListViewWordDescriptionOnline" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="Fill">
              <ListView.ItemTemplate  >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid>
                            <Label     Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="#7D7D7D"  FontSize="14" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label     Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference root},
                          Path=BingStringValue}"   />
                            <Image  Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference root},
                          Path=BingImageValue}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
 </ContentPage>
```